# can two structs defined in same class can access each other?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct

if i have a class books having two *struct*

```
struct A{
    B *ptr;   //it says identifier undefined 
};
struct B{

};
```

Both are defined in same class. is it possible to save the pointer of struct B in struct A as i have mentioned above?
can anyone help plz?

Comment: Put `struct B` before `struct A`.

Comment: [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: @jrok oooppps =p thanks ALOT for correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare `struct B` first:

```
struct B;
struct A{
    B *ptr;   //it says identifier undefined 
};
struct B{

};
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++ all symbols have to be declared before they are used. So simply put the `B` structure before the `A` structure.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
struct B;
```

first and you're done. This tells the compiler that there will be a `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you just have to *`declare the structure name before` the structure in which you use the instance*.

```
struct B; // declared before struct A, now the problem is gone.

struct A{
    B *ptr;   //it says identifier undefined 
};


struct B{

};
```

Answer (score 1):

place strut B before struct A.

```
 class book
{
struct B
{

};
struct A
{
 B * ptr;         
};

};
```

place struct B befor struct A.